# Equivalent of this string replacement code in R?

Tags: python, arrays, r, string

I have the following code that works really well to remove characters from the end of elements in a Python list:

```
x = ['01/01/2013 00:00:00','01/01/2013 00:00:00',
    '01/01/2013 00:00:00','01/01/2013 00:00:00',...]
```

Assuming that array, I want to remove the `00:00:00` part. So, I wrote this:

```
i = 0
while i < len(x):
    x[i] = x[i][:x[i].find(' 00:00:00')]
    i += 1
```

This does the trick. How can I implement a similar solution in R? I've tried `substr` and `gsub`, but they run really slow (the actual list has over 250,000 date/time combos).

Comment: do you just want strings or to parse to date/time

Comment: If you'd like it as an actual `Date` object, you can use `as.Date(x, format = '%d/%m/%Y')` (or `'%m/%d/%Y'` if it's month/day/year; I can't tell).

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
x <- rep('01/01/2013 00:00:00', 250000)
system.time(y <- sub(" 00:00:00", "", x, fixed=TRUE))
# User      System verstrichen 
# 0.05        0.00        0.05
```

`y` contains the result. Timing shows that it should not take too long. See `?sub` for help on the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Consider some sample data:

```
set.seed(144)
dat <- sample(c("01/01/2013 00:00:00", "01/01/2013 12:34:56"), 200000, replace=T)
table(dat)
# dat
# 01/01/2013 00:00:00 01/01/2013 12:34:56 
#              100100               99900
```

Here, we want to remove the trailing 00:00:00 but keep the trailing 12:34:56.

You could first find 00:00:00 at the end of the string with the following (runs in ~0.1 seconds on my computer):

```
to.clean <- grepl(" 00:00:00$", dat)
```

Now you can use `substr` to remove the relevant trailing characters (runs in ~0.04 seconds on my computer):

```
dat[to.clean] <- substr(dat[to.clean], 1, nchar(dat[to.clean])-9)
table(dat)
# dat
#          01/01/2013 01/01/2013 12:34:56 
#              100100               99900
```

Alternately, the following more compact `gsub` command also runs in about 0.15 seconds for these 200,000 date/time pairs:

```
cleaned <- gsub(" 00:00:00$", "", dat)
table(cleaned)
# cleaned
#          01/01/2013 01/01/2013 12:34:56 
#              100100               99900
```

It's possible that you were looping through the data and separately calling `substr` or `gsub` on each individual element of your vector, which would certainly be expected to be much slower since it doesn't take advantage of vectorization.